# Assigning password to multiple workbooks in a given folder

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Let me tell you the issue. We prepare summary report, based on a report I can split files in separate workbooks.

The main problem is:

I tried many ways to protect Multiple workbooks with a different password. In my excel password file have all list of excel names in column A and list of a different password in column B ( minimum 100 excel files and it may reach 500 files maximum) according to excel column A name need to assign password column B in folder workbook. It's really painful to do for every month manually

Is there an easy way to protect multiple workbooks without opening each one and assigning password through VBA codes? As per my knowledge, we can assign the same password to all workbook, but am looking different password according to my excel stored password as required

Really appreciate your help

Comment: _"I tried many ways to protect Multiple workbooks with different password"_: show us one of those ways

Comment: Thank you for your reply....

Comment: Sub Passwordprotect()
'Open password protected files
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Workbooks.Open "C:\Cb.xlsx", False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Cb.xlsx", Password:="basu"
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub


here am writing daily manually ... it taking long time and even for 500 excel names and path i need to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible solution

```
Sub protectwpwd()
Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    i = 1
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    While ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Workbooks.Open ws.Cells(i, 1)
        ActiveWorkbook.Saveas ws.cells(i,1),Password:=ws.Cells(i, 2)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the code am getting error because how to write code to search my folder within code to assign passwords

Comment: through loop .... yes we can ... need to modify as it should look into folder which i can give then it should start assigning as mentioned column A excel names and column B passwords keep looping till end please help me

Comment: Please modify how to loop in folder directory

Comment: Sub protectwpwd()

Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Dim directory As String, fileName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

directory = "c:\VBA\"

fileName = Dir(directory & ".xlsx")

    i = 1

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    While ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

        Workbooks.Open ws.Cells(i, 1)

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ws.Cells(i, 1), Password:=ws.Cells(i, 2)

        ActiveWorkbook.Close

        i = i + 1

    Wend

End Sub

Comment: created loop still not working ... Run time error - "1004" Sorry , we couldnot find details.xlsx , is it possible it was moved or deleted ?  Here i checked twice i can able to find excel xlsx name ...  how to fix

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want to achieve.my understanding : you have a list of files in column A and the password that you want to set for each file in column B. Why would you need to scan a directory ?

Comment: So you don't have the list of files in column A nor the desired passwords ?

Comment: Yes i have list of column A names and column B is excel  if am looping means how it take to folders excel path. Path i need to mention in column A by looking am doing modificaton

Comment: Public Sub test()
Dim wbk As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String, i As Long
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\VBA\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    'Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    i = 1
    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wbk.ActiveSheet
    
    Debug.Print ws.Name
  
    While ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Workbooks.Open ws.Cells(i, 1)

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ws.Cells(i, 1), Password:=ws.Cells(i, 2)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    wbk.Close True
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub